# Is it possible to transform the double matrix columns to list or pair?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code to generate the Jaccard similarity using pandas.

here is my example of dataframe

```
doc1 doc2   all_doc
BD   10     ID8
BD   16     ID7
BD   14     ID6
BD   24     ID5
.
.
.
BC   90     IDN
```

that created by this code

```
df = df_doc1.merge(df_doc2, on='all_doc', how='outer').set_index(['doc1','doc2'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

then I calculate the Jaccard by this code

```
sim_prepared = df.set_index(['doc1', 'doc2'])
sim_prepared = sim_prepared[sim_prepared.all_doc != '0']

sim_prepared
sim_mat = pd.get_dummies(sim_prepared.all_doc).sort_index(level=0).max(level=[0,1])

grp=sim_mat
dist = pdist(grp, metric="jaccard")
s_dist = squareform(dist)
sim = np.subtract(1, s_dist)
sim_df = pd.DataFrame(sim, columns=grp.index, index=grp.index)
sim_df
```

and I got this matrix

```
     doc1 BD   BD    BD    BD 
     doc2 10   16    14    24
doc1 doc2
BD   10   1    0.4   0.1   0.3
BD   16   0.1   1    0.3   0.4 
BD   14   0.5  0.1    1    0.3
BD   24   0.8  0.9   0.4    1 
.
.
.
```

I want to see the result become to something this (just in pair or list or order)
for example

```
[(BD/10),(BD/10)]       1
[(BD/10),(BD/16)]       0.4
[(BD/10),(BD/14)]       0.1
[(BD/10),(BD/24)]       0.3
.
.
.
[(BD/24,(BD/24)]          1
```

how can I solve this problem? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove the levels from your MultiIndices, making them tuples, and then stack.

```
sim_df.index = [*sim_df.index]
sim_df.columns = [*sim_df.columns]
sim_df.stack()

(BD, 10)  (BD, 10)    1.0
          (BD, 14)    0.4
          (BD, 16)    0.1
          (BD, 24)    0.3
(BD, 14)  (BD, 10)    0.1
          (BD, 14)    1.0
          (BD, 16)    0.3
          (BD, 24)    0.4
(BD, 16)  (BD, 10)    0.5
          (BD, 14)    0.1
          (BD, 16)    1.0
          (BD, 24)    0.3
(BD, 24)  (BD, 10)    0.8
          (BD, 14)    0.9
          (BD, 16)    0.4
          (BD, 24)    1.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Input Data: `sim_df`

```
doc1        BD               
doc2        10   14   16   24
doc1 doc2                    
BD   10    1.0  0.4  0.1  0.3
     14    0.1  1.0  0.3  0.4
     16    0.5  0.1  1.0  0.3
     24    0.8  0.9  0.4  1.0
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have followed your suggestion but I got this error -> TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument. T T I would like to ask, How can I solve this issue?